# Реализовать поиск по сайту

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть?))
Хочу сделать поиск по сайту. Поле поиска планирую расположить в главном меню. Сайт имеет структуру - хедер с меню, футер, 2 небольшие боковые панели и основная центральная область. При работе различных представлений меняется только центральная часть.  Соответственно, для пользователя всегда доступно поле поиска.
Видимо, нужно отдельное представление для поиска. Тогда когда и как оно будет запускаться?

Comment: Покопайте в сторону `context_processors`

Comment: Поле поиска - это форма с одним полем. При ее сабмите - происходит переход на страницу результатов поиска. В чем вопрос?